# Only button being shown when taking picture with camera in iPad 2

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ipad-2

I'm presenting my camera using a popover. It works perfectly in  my iPad.

For my surprise in iPad 2 when the camera is summoned only the grey bar with the take picture button appears, but the image that shows what the camera sees is invisible, even weirder, only the underlying view is visible. If the user touches the camera button THEN the image appears, showing the photo just taken.

Any idea of what could be the cause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opening the camera uses a lot of memory. this causes a memory warning, which in turn remove unused views and objects with a retain count 0.

1. verify that if "viewDidLoad" is called twice it wont break your logic, as it can happen on memory warning.
2. check if you are trying to use an object with retain count 0

Comment: Yep, memory seemed to be the culprit.